# Classic ASP + ADODB -- how to see actual query being run (for testing)

Tags: asp-classic, adodb

I'm using Classic ASP.  I have a wrapper function for database queries that accepts a query string and an array of parameters, and auto-creates the proper query object and runs the query.  Very handy and has been working great.

Here's my problem:  When testing, I often want to see the exact text of the query being passed to SQL.  Back in the "bad old days" of assembling queries through concatenation I could just write out the string.  Now that I'm using parameterization it's a bit more tricky.

How do I take a peek at the fully-assembled query string just before it's passed to the database connection?

Here is the function I'm using, simplified. (The actual function doesn't assume string, for example.)

```
Public Function pquery( strQuery, params )
    Dim cmd, param, thisParam, rs
    Set cmd = Server.CreateObject( "ADODB.Command" )
    cmd.ActiveConnection = MyConn
    cmd.CommandText = strQuery
    If IsArray( params ) then
        Dim adVarChar : adVarChar = 200
        For Each param In params
            Set thisParam = cmd.CreateParameter( "@p", adVarChar, , len( param ), param )
            cmd.Parameters.Append thisParam
        Next
    End If
    Set rs = cmd.Execute
    Set pquery = rs
End Function
```

Comment: Maybe somehow access ConnectionString ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider using [Sql Query Profiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091(v=sql.105).aspx), as it'll allow you to view the sql text as well as the values being passed in. It'll allow you to set breakpoints, as well as see how long it takes to run a query. However, this requires the query to be sent to the actual database (you had asked for before).

To do it beforehand, you would need to loop through the parameters collection in the command object, then do a find/replace with the key/value pairs in the command text property. it would be hackish at best, if you can use Profiler, go with that.

Comment: I don't mind if it actually gets sent -- it's test data on a test server anyway. I just want to see exactly what does get sent.  Thanks.

Comment: ya then Profiler is your solution. such a handy tool